# How to get user ids of current user's followers with the spotify web api?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, spotify, bearer-token

Seems simple enough but can't seem to find how to get user ids my current user's followers in their documentation?

The related documentation is located here:

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference-beta/#category-user-profile

It states that calling their 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me' endpoint I can retrieve the current user's profile based on the authorization token I send. However the only information about user's followers is simply the number of followers they have. I would like to be able to retrieve my logged in user's followers and then use their follower's user ids to make other api calls (which seems fine as long as the other users have also allowed my application access to their data).

Am I missing a scope in my initial authorization request that is hiding this information? Can I not see this information because the followers of my current user have not allowed permission to my application? Is there a different endpoint I need to use in order to retrieve this information?

If this information is needed, I have used the Implicit Grant Flow Model with my Angular frontend to retrieve my bearer token.

Thank you!

Comment: You can (with the right 'scope') retrieve a list of the Artists the user is following but you cannot retrieve a list of the users they follow.

Comment: yikes, then doing what I want to do just got a lot harder /: I guess I'll have to maintain a list of user ids that have signed into my app and then have my own search function to find users by name and have a lookup to their ID that way. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

As scgough said in the comments, it appears that with the right scope set I could get a list of the Artists the user is following, but no scope will allow me to get a list of the current user's the user is following (other than just the number).